# Access sActualFieldValue

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on a database that was created years ago by a colleague and updated most recently by a software designer who in his words has "bowed out" of servicing it as our database has become too complex.

I've received the following Run-time error '13":  Type Mismatch.

The hi-lighted error is:

Me.Controls("Label" & i & "Desc").Caption = DLookup("[Description]", "tbl_Contract_Items", "[Mat_Item_No]='" & sActualFieldValue & "'")

It is a billing database, we bill our customer with item numbers like 1.23, 2.31, 24.02.03 and 21.03.15.  Items with the single decimal work fine but it is the items with two decimals that cause the error. ie 24.02.03.  The issue is new and was not a problem until recently.

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim sActualFieldValue

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qxt_tbl_WEC_Qty_Crosstab1")

For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count - 1 'rs(0) is Date

    If i > 14 Then Exit For

    sActualFieldValue = Replace(rs(i).Name, "_", ".", , 1)

    Me.Controls("Text" & i).ControlSource = rs(i).Name
    Me.Controls("Label" & i).Caption = sActualFieldValue
    Me.Controls("Label" & i & "Desc").Caption = DLookup("[Description]", "tbl_Contract_Items", "[Mat_Item_No]='" & sActualFieldValue & "'")
    Me.Controls("Text" & i & "Tot").ControlSource = "=sum([" & rs(i).Name & "])"
Next

'Stop
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Tom, I can't really help you with your problem, unfortunately, since I'm not a VBA expert, one thing to note - people who reply here are all volunteers and some might not appreciated "need help ASAP", as your job emergencies are not their problems. Back to the topic, you might want to remove the second dot in your number since it's not needed for anything, right?

Comment: If you want help fast, I suggest to start with tagging your question appropriately. the access tag excerpt says _DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use [ms-access] instead_ and this code seems to be VBA code, not vb.net code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments .  I apologize if I "ASAP" was rude, it wasn't intended.  oblio, yes, the second dot is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property *Caption* must be a string, but *DLookup* returns *Null* for not found. So wrap in *Nz()*:

```
Me.Controls("Label" & i & "Desc").Caption = Nz(DLookup("[Description]", "tbl_Contract_Items", "[Mat_Item_No]='" & sActualFieldValue & "'"))
```

Comment: Hey Gustav, thank you very much. I will give ot a shot. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Guatav, that fixed the issue but caused an error to the line beow it. Included Nz to it and it works.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay. I'm not familiar with the site yet.